# smooth scrolling and get back button with popState on Firefox - need to click twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm trying to implement a small code with which I can get smooth scrolling when I click on anchor (and anchor name appears after animation) and I would like to return to the top of page if I push on the back button of the browser and update the URL (without #anchor name).

Here's the code :

```
$(function() {
  // Smooth scrolling when clicking on anchor
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        var hash = this.hash; 
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 55}, 300, function() {
          location.hash = hash;
          href = window.location.href;
          history.pushState({page:href}, null, href);
        });
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  // Get smooth scrolling to the top whith back button of browser
  $(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
    var state = event.originalEvent.state;
    var target = window.location.href.split('#');
    var href = target[0];
    if (state) {
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300, function() {
        window.location.href = href;
     })
   }
  });

  // First page loading
  window.onload = function() {
    history.replaceState({ path: window.location.href }, '');
  }
});
```

All the above functionalities work well under Safari and Chrome. But this is not the case with Firefox: once smooth scrolling down is performed, I need to click twice on back button to be redirected on the top of page.

I have seen [this other question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634518/popstate-need-to-click-twice-on-back-button-to-actually-get-back) and tried to do with and without event.preventDefault, also by putting only :

```
$('html').animate
```

or `$('body').animate`

but the behavior is the same.

If someone could see why it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: it works for me in FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering additional history change in this line `location.hash = hash;`

So, I did a couple of changes to your code, and it works in my FF now.

In click handler,

```
   $('html').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 55}, 300, function() {
      href = window.location.href;
      history.pushState({page:href}, null, href.split('#')[0]+hash);
    });
```

Also, it seems like `$('html,body').animate` runs callback twice, therefore messing with history. That's why I left only html.

In popstate handler I removed page reload, but you can keep it, if you wish:

```
if (state) {
  $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems to work well but I would like to avoid reloading the page when I return to the top of page : is it possible to modify the URL (actually remove the #anchor) without using "window.location.href = href" ?

Comment: Another remark : If I don't use callback into $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300), the animation is not achieved (smooth scrolling), I go directly to anchor without smooth scrolling.

Comment: Finally, I used "history.pushState({}, null, newUrl)" to return to top without reloading page, thanks

Comment: @user1773603 Last 3 lines of my answer are about page reload. Didn't removal of `window.location.href = href;` work?

Comment: I replaced by "history.replaceState({}, null, href)" and with this, it doesn't reload page, thanks